# Pass a form name to a function in a module

Tags: vb.net, forms, function

I need to reference a textbox on a form from a module.  The following works great except I have to Hard Code the form name (frmForm1).  I am using this from several forms. How can I have the function use the form name I am sending (Me)?

I call the function, and I would like to send the form name, from my form:

```
ModuleFunction(Me)
```

In the Module I have this Function:

```
Public Function ModuleFunction(ByRef frmFrom As frmForm1) As Boolean

    frmFrom.txtTextBox1.Text = "something"
    ......

End Function
```

Comment: Looks like some sort of VB. Might want to edit in a tag like [vbscript] or [vba] or [vb.net] depending on your language.

Comment: It is VB.Net.  I get how to pass variables to and from Functions but the "(ByRef frmFrom As frmForm1)" is throwing me.  I pass the form name but I am not sure how to recieve it in the function in place of the hard coded "frmForm1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get around this by using `Controls` instead:

```
Public Function ModuleFunction(ByRef frmFrom As Form) As Boolean

    frmFrom.Controls("txtTextBox1").Text = "something"
    ......

End Function
```

You should be able to pass in a `frmForm1` directly because it inherits from `Form`. But as soon as you tried to access the member `txtTextBox1` it wouldn't compile, because `Form` has no knowledge of that specific member - only its child does. But `Form` does have a defined `Controls` collection containing all of these control members, allowing you to access your control through the magic of polymorphism.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks very much and have a great day :)

Comment: Well a new issue using the same concept..  I am trying to use this concept with a DataGridView  using the DataSource property:
frmFrom.Controls("DataGridView").DataSource = BindingSource and I get 'DataSource' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'